# Looping through an array via a foreach to display some data, and using the same array to show a single output

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sending to the blade the following output from a query which has 5 rows. Each row has a question and an answer, where the question is the same in the 5 rows, while the answer is different in each row. 
I want to show the question only once, and underneath it the 5 answers.
I'm sending an array as below :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#338 ▼
    +"id": 25
    +"created_at": "2019-10-18 11:13:17"
    +"updated_at": "2019-10-18 11:13:17"
    +"title": "question"
    +"body": """
       \r\n
         aasasas
      """
    +"ttype": 0
    +"cat": 0
    +"a_id": 25
    +"tag": ""
    +"appr": 0
    +"user_id": 6
    +"comment_id": 0
    +"parent_id": null
    +"ppoints": null
    +"status": 0
    +"arank": 1
    +"qatype": 1
    +"country": "Egypt"
    +"wwide": 0
  }
```

The following shows the question once and the answer more than once for this question. Of course this code gives `Trying to get property of non-object` error because it is expecting a foreach for the question as well.

```
@if(!empty($updt_11))

<p class="collapsible"> {{$updt_11->title}} </p> // this is the question

@foreach($updt_11 as $updt_11_a)   
<div class= "content">
<p>{{$updt_11_a->body}} </p>   //This is the answer
</div>
@endforeach
@endif
```

How can I put the question once and the answer multiple times using the same array?

Comment: Can you show us your table structure? Or models? Because it is hard to understand what exactly you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if you can change in the array from the backend and add quetion one time an in sub array pass answer than its easy for you.

if you want to do with the same array you have passed then do

Point 1. use `index` of `0` to display  question

Point 2. as you have already used , use `foreach` to display answers

```
@if(!empty($updt_11))

<p class="collapsible"> {{$updt_11[0]->title}} </p> // this is the question

@foreach($updt_11 as $updt_11_a)   
<div class= "content">
<p>{{$updt_11_a->body}} </p>   //This is the answer
</div>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have array into an array so you need to two-time run `foreach()`.

```
@if(!empty($updt_11))

    <p class="collapsible"> {{$updt_11[0]->title}} </p> // this is the question

    @foreach($updt_11 as $updt_11_a)
        @foreach($updt_11_a as $updt_11_b)  // Assume array into array.
            <div class= "content">
               <p>{{$updt_11_b->body}} </p>   //This is the answer
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Thanks..